# How to activate adsense account?

Tags: youtube, adsense

I'm having some problem with Google Adsense. I created a blog using Blogger almost one year ago and YouTube channel four days ago, but when I tried to link both of them with my AdSense account it always gives me this message, " You are currently signed into Google account which is either not an active Adsense account or still pending an approval".
Even no email was received from AdSense according to its activation.

How to active my Adsense account and link it with my Youtube Channel and Blogger? Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unrelated to programming.

Answer (score 0):

This message clearly says that your AdSense account is not approved yet, what you have to do?
Wait for their reply, if they declined the approval. Wait for few months meanwhile ensure the following facts about the website and then reapply for AdSense approval

- Write quality content only
- Content must be grammatically correct and free from spelling mistakes
- Content must be original, must not be derived from another website
- The website should have a simple website layout which can be navigate easily
- The website should contain a number of posts, do not write few posts and apply to the Google AdSense for approval
- Website must not have any pornography or adult content
- Website must have organic and genuine traffic

These points are taken from [**Before applying to Google AdSense, you should focus on some of these points**](http://www.duggu.org/google-adsense/before-applying-to-google-adsense-you-should-focus-on-some-of-these-points.aspx)